# ImageLoader refreshing images on tab change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-imageview

In my getView (for my adapter) I do

```
    ImageView malImage = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.animelist_malimg); // thumb image

    HashMap<String, String> anime = new HashMap<String, String>();

    anime = data.get(position);

    //...

    String img_url = anime.get(AnimeListFragment.KEY_MALIMG_URL);

    malImage.setTag(img_url);

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(img_url, malImage);
```

When I change tabs, if it's only one over from the current it seems fine, but if it's two or more over it will refresh the images and it flashes the placeholder image for a moment. Is there any reasonable way to avoid this?

Comment: It is default behavior of `listView` or `gridView` to optimize this use `view holder pattern`

Comment: I ended up here: http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166 and tried that method, but that didn't seem to help the reloading issue. I even tried setting the image only when the view is newly inflated and that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I was being an idiot. In the tutorial I read, in the adapter constructor it would initialize a new ImageLoader. This is bad. I made a public, static ImageLoader in my MainActivity and shared that across all of my adapters and that seemed to work perfectly.

I did learn some new tricks thanks to this topic, so thank you for attempting to help me.